# Get object elements Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects. I loop on the array objects, so i get all objects stored in the array. Now i want to get the elements of any object individualy.

I tried this code to manage this, but in the output i get the whole element of the object.

```
function loadPropertiesFromJson(propertiesArray)
{
    $.each(propertiesArray, function(idx, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        console.log(key + ": " + value.key);
      });
   });
}
```

Is there a way to get the elements of the object individualy?

My array of the objects is like this:

```
 [
   {"id":"aa","name":"bb","type":"cc"},
   {"id":"ee","name":"rr","type":"ff"}
 ]
```

And i want to get the id, name,.... individualy and store theme into a variables.

There is a way to manage this?

Comment: You mean you want to get all the names and put them in their own array, or you want the name of a specific item? If the latter, access the array by index: `array[0].name`

Comment: Perfect, they work for me, i just deleted the second loop and access to the object elements throw the array like this 'propertiesArray[idx].id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by accessing the attributes in a given index:

```js
var propertiesArray= [{
    "id": "aa",
    "name": "bb",
    "type": "cc"
  },
  {
    "id": "ee",
    "name": "rr",
    "type": "ff"
  }
];

console.log("ID: "+propertiesArray[0].id);
console.log("Name: "+propertiesArray[0].name);
console.log("-------------");
console.log("ID: "+propertiesArray[1].id);
console.log("Name: "+propertiesArray[1].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does I correctly understand you want to get each item value.
So just remove key at the end of second loop: value.key in your each loop:

```
function loadPropertiesFromJson(propertiesArray)
{
    $.each(propertiesArray, function(idx, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        console.log(key + ": " + value);
      });
   });
}
```

It returns all values seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/k5sgn8xn/

```js
var data = [
   {"id":"aa","name":"bb","type":"cc"},
   {"id":"ee","name":"rr","type":"ff"}
 ];
 
 $.each(data, function(key){
  $.each(data[key], function(k, v){
   $('div:eq("' + key + '")').attr(k, v);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   test1
</div>
<div>
   test2
</div>
```

This will help you to added attribute to **N** numbers of containers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
The solution of @Mathias Falci works for me.

There is the code that works:

```
$.each(propertiesArray, function(idx, obj){ 

        console.log(propertiesArray[idx].id);

});
```